# as3, function active after 3 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, function, timer

I have 2 functions going in as3:

```
function blueDownBounce (e:MouseEvent):void {
    var blueDownY:Tween = new Tween(blue, "y", Regular.easeOut, -49, -19, 1, true);
}
blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, blueDownBounce);

function blueUpBounce (e:MouseEvent):void {
    var blueUpY:Tween = new Tween(blue, "y", Bounce.easeOut, -19, -49, 1, true);
}
blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, blueUpBounce);
```

I am trying to make it so that these functions are active after 3 seconds and they stay active for the whole time it is stopped on that frame after those 3 seconds. I know you have to make a timer and make it dependent on that timer but it wasn't working out well.

Thanks,
Wade

Comment: Are you trying to call `blueDownBounce` three seconds after the mouse over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function needed to be defined above the timer and the event listener needed to be in the timer.